# Facing problem MongoDb installation on Ubantu 22 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

Is it possible to install MongoDb on ubantu 22 LTS? I can't install MongoDb on it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from https://idroot.us/install-mongodb-ubuntu-22-04/ blog.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).